# HTML5 stream m3u radio player

Tags: html, html5-audio, internet-radio, m3u

I have a problem with building HTML5 audio player using m3u format.

I have tried do it like this:

```
<audio id="audio-player" src="http://fm101.uz:9900/mobile.m3u" type="audio/aacp" controls="controls"></audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the m3u extension use the true `url`, you can discover this `url` opening the `m3u` file on winamp (or another audio program) and on the playlist window, right-click, properties and you can see "http://fm101.uz:9900/fm101_high" or something similar.

```
<audio src="http://fm101.uz:9900/fm101_high" controls="controls"> </audio>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h4oo9012/1/