# HTML5 audio tag not playing anymore in Chrome 58.0.3029.81

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio

Since last Google Chrome update  58.0.3029.81 my code doesn't wok anymore:

```
        <audio id="player" src="http://serverip/stream.m3u" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume += 0.1">Vol+ </button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.1">Vol- </button>
</div>
```

I can confirm that the above code works perfectly on another laptop with an older Google Chrome version 50.0.2661.95. I also checked on a MacBook with Safari and it works fine as well.

I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light as I am really struggling to find a working solution.

Many thanks for your kind help!

Comment: bro it's work . i also used Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit) ... and Its Work Fine In My Browser. .

Comment: reset your browser setting .. of Chrome and Try again .. Its Work Fine

Comment: chrome://settings/search#reset ... and Reset Your Browser Setting...

Comment: I have tried that no luck. I am struggling now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Code Is Perfectly Work Fine in Chrome update 58.0.3029.81 !!**

> You Can Try To Reset Your Browser Settings and Then Try This i Hope Its Work For You !!:
>   [chrome://settings/search#reset](http://chrome://settings/search#reset%20.)

```
<audio id="player" src="C:\Users\Rishii\Downloads\Parineeti-Chopra-Ayushman.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume += 0.1">Vol+ </button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.1">Vol- </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your kind advice. I have tried to reset the browser settings but to no avail.

Comment: Hmm.. now you can just uninstall it !! Then re install.. from official site or you can from file hippo.. or file horse ..  Try One More Time.. :)

Comment: Cool. I will try and come back to you. Fingers crossed! Also if you get a chance can you please try with a file.m3u instead of.mp3 . Just in case there is a compatibility issue with that format. Cheers!

Comment: Okk got it... HTML 5 only supports mp3 off and wav file currently.. you can Google it about m3u file is supported in HTML 5 with chorme or not. It's only work in iOS file.

Comment: I see that's why then it works only on my iDevices. That's a real shame though.Thanks for checking. Much appreciated.

Comment: Great, please let me know then!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546013/html5-stream-m3u-radio-player  ... Check it Out This ...

Comment: Fab, I will check it and come back to you! Thanks a lot buddy!

Comment: All sorted as I posted on the 24th of April (scroll a bit up) and I then I voted your anwer.Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

All sorted. I ended up changing the stream from .m3u to .mp3 and it worked like a charm! Thanks for your help and for confirming that .mp3 was working for you. That helped me to find the solution for me.

Comment: what you did ??